# OpenApi 3 does not document my JPA Repositories in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, swagger, openapi

does anybody know if with OpenApi 3 is it possible to document my JPA Repositories in Spring Boot? Because I still haven't found a proper solution.

Comment: OpenAPI is for REST APIs, not for database respositories. Unless you expose them via Spring Data REST.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI is a framework to document REST APIs.
if you want to document your JPA Repositories methods, you need to create corresponding REST api.